# Open fragment from notification when the app in background

Tags: android, android-fragments, parse-platform, android-broadcast

I am using parse to push `Json` notifications to my app with custom receiver because I want to navigate to different places in the app and that's depends on `Json` value I receive, I have 2 cases to navigate:

a) 7

b) 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

case `a` opens an `activity` and that's works as normal.
case `b` open a `fragment` in the `MainActivity. "Here's the problem."

I tried to open the `MainActivity` with normal intent then replace the container of it with the fragment.

When I try to open case `b` I got `ClassCastException` in the third line from this snippet because it's cannot cast the `BaseClass` context to v4 fragment.
I got the same exception when I give it just the `context` that belongs to the receiver context.

```
intent = new Intent(context, MainScreen.class);
Fragment fragment = new NotificationFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = ((FragmentActivity) context.getApplicationContext()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
```

That's the exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myapp.SomeApp, PID: 9639
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.myapp.SomeApp.Receivers.NotifyReceiver: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.myapp.SomeApp.utils.BaseClass cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2616)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:151)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1380)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:114)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.myapp.SomeApp.utils.BaseClass cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
 at com.myapp.SomeApp.Receivers.NotifyReceiver.onReceive(NotifyReceiver.java:52)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2609)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:151) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1380) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
 at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:114)
```

That's the full receiver code:

```
public class NotifyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private String title, itemID, notifyType;
private int id;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (intent != null) {
        try {
            String response = intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data");

            JSONObject data = new JSONObject(response);
            itemID = data.getString("ItemID");
            notifyType = data.getString("NotificationTypeID");
            title = data.getString("alert");

            id = Integer.parseInt(notifyType);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("NotifyReceiver", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    if (id == 7) {
        intent = new Intent(context, TendersActivity.class);
    } else {
        intent = new Intent(context, MainScreen.class);
        Fragment fragment = new NotificationFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction =
                ((FragmentActivity) context.getApplicationContext())
                        .getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
    }
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

    Notification notify = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(title)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notify)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{250, 250, 250, 250})
            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0, notify);
    }
}
```

Comment: Bro you want to start fragment from NotifyReceiver  right?

Comment: @saeed Yup that what am trying to do.

Comment: Pass an extra in the Intent, then in onCreate() in MainScreen.java, perform the FragmentTransaction if the extra is set.

Comment: @DanielNugent I will give a try.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please replace your else section by this code:

```
else {
        intent = new Intent(context, MainScreen.class);
        resultIntent.putExtra("From", "notifyFrag");
    }
```

And in your `MainScreen.class` check that if the activity called from notification key using this code:

```
String type = getIntent().getStringExtra("From");
if (type != null) {
    switch (type) {
        case "notifyFrag":
            Fragment fragment = new NotificationFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
            break;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Let me Know your result

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using this line. This is where the BaseClass context is coming from.

```
((FragmentActivity) context.getApplicationContext())
```

Comment: I know, I just was giving a try, I said I used the receiver context but I got the same exception.

Comment: You should be starting an activity instead of a fragment, and then add the fragment. Where are you supposedly adding this fragment? How will fragment manager know what is R.id.container?

Comment: bro, read the question again and the code. That's what i already tried.

Comment: Can you share the code when you tried it via MainActivity?

Comment: If you looked at the first line after `else`  you will see it!

Comment: Why are you explicitly casting there?